# App indexing same site, different url

Tags: android, google-app-engine, url, android-app-indexing

So, I am trying to implement app indexing into my app. Everything works fine, except this:

My website has 2 urls for one screen. One is user friendly, one is for us programmers. 
User friendly: http://www.akcijeikatalozi.rs/akcije-katalozi/metro-akcija-odlicne-cene-prehrane-29102015-11112015-8031

Programmer url:http://www.akcijeikatalozi.rs/katalog/katalog/view/id/8031

Now, when user wants to visit site, they will get the user friendly url, but I cannot get anything from the user friendly url, only from the programming url.
How can I switch between these 2 urls in my application so my app indexing is going to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of canonical URLs to show users your preferred URL when they search for it.
On how to do that, you find more information here - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Regarding on passing information to your App, since you are using canonical URLs, you can use either URL type for the deep links.
A deep link annotation will be similar to this:

```
[android-app://apk_name/http/akcijeikatalozi.rs/katalog/katalog/view/id/8031]
```

In the Google documentation you have more information on how to construct and publish your deep links. 
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app

Cheers.